# Why does a total cost of $0 results in charge of $2.10 on AppEngine billing?

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

I have this in my AppEngine Billing History:

```
2011-11-14 12:54:58  Usage Report for 2011-11-13     $2.10   <-- ???
Resource    Used    Free    Billable    Charge
```

...

```
Total: (before clipping to daily budget)     $0.00 <-- ???
```

So the total is 0.00 and I get charged 2.10 ?

Comment: $2.10 represents one week's worth of the $9 monthly minimum charge for billed apps.